# AngularJS: Pub/Sub vs View events vs JS Reference

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, publish-subscribe

I'm trying to make my angular app reactive - I'm using angular v1.4 and Ionic v1.2.
The example is a blog app with the option to favorite posts.
The posts and the favorites are handled with different controllers that have to communicate. All my data is abstracted on services.

I started to use the Ionic view events (p.e. `$ionicView.afterEnter`) to fill the ViewModel. Each time the user enters the view, I check if there's data, if not fetch/get some.
After that, I implemented a Pub/Sub mechanism with angular `$on/$broadcast` event system.

Both of these approaches felt like overkills, so I now use Javascript reference capabilities - with `angular.copy`- to keep everything in sync.

Here's a jsbin with each example: https://jsbin.com/waxawev/3/edit?js

My questions are:

- what's the recommended pattern?
- what is the most performant?
- what approach will scale better and why?

Thank you.

Comment: There is no exact answer, sometimes one is better, sometimes another one. ..

Comment: We all know that patterns will ultimately be about personal/project preferences, but I'm asking for opinions on the subject, regarding the questions I made. You can point out examples too.